# SQL query of Sum and Count from multiple tables

Tags: sql, count, sum, multiple-tables

I have the following two tables:

**1. BList**

- BookingID
- AdultNo
- ChildNo
- BookingDate

**2. BHandle**

- BookingID
- TicketingStatus
- FinalSellingPrice
- FinalNett
- Staff

What I want to do is get the `distinct Staff` with `Sum of (SellingPrice)` , `Sum of (NettPrice)`, `Profit (Sum of sellingPrice)- Sum of (NettPrice))`, No of Pax which is `(AdultNo + ChildNo)` and also count the `BookingID` as No of Bookings

```
WHERE BookingDate >= fromDate AND BookingDate <= toDate 
    AND TicketingStatus='CP'
```

Something that looks like this (The Total figures at the bottom doesn't matter as i will write them to csv format, i will handle the total there) but i need to figure out how to get the query first.

[image: The list that i want to produce]

This is the query i can get from the 2nd Table **BHandle**

```
SELECT Staff, SUM(FinalSellingPrice) AS gross, SUM(FinalNett) AS cost
FROM BHandle
WHERE ticketingstatus ='CP'
GROUP BY Staff
```

This is my query for the 1st table **BList**

```
SELECT (adultno+childno) AS pax 
fFROM om BList
WHERE bookingdate >='01-mar-2013 00:00'
AND bookingdate <= '15-may-2013 23:59'
```

How can I combine these 2 queries together?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this (assuming all columns are non null):

```
select Staff,
    sum(FinalSellingPrice) as gross,
    sum(FinalNett) as cost,
    sum(FinalSellingPrice - FinalNett) as profit,
    sum(AdultNo+ChildNo) as pax,
    count(1) as bookings
from Blist b
inner join BHandle bh on b.BookingID = bh.BookingID
where b.BookingDate >= fromDate
    and b.BookingDate <= toDate
    and bh.TicketingStatus = 'CP'
group by staff;
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is using `union all` with an aggregation:

```
select staff, sum(gross) as gross, sum(cost) as cost, sum(pax) as pax,
       sum(numbookings) as numbookings
from ((SELECT Staff, SUM(FinalSellingPrice) AS gross, SUM(FinalNett) AS cost,
              null as pax, null as numbookings
       FROM BHandle
       WHERE ticketingstatus ='CP'
       GROUP BY Staff
      ) union all
      (select staff, null as gross, null as cost, (adultno+childno) AS pax ,
              count(*) as numbookings
       from blist join
            bhandle
            on blist.bookingid = bhandle.bookingid
       group by staff
      )
     ) t
group by staff
```

Comment: i doesn's have Staff in BList table. Is giving me an error 'Invalid column name Staff'